# Xaml Image Format

Tags: c#, html, xml, xaml, xamarin

How would I center the thumbnail images vertically and horizontally inside the image tags? I want some type of container for images that can take in any size/dimensions of an image and format it to look pretty and neat.

I have tried

```
<Image VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

but it doesnt affect the position of the image at all..

[image]

```
<ListView x:Name="VideoListView" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemTapped="ViewCellItem_Clicked">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="10" Padding="10, 10, 10, 10" > <!-- "left, top, right, bottom" -->
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/> 
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/> 
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image 
                                Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" 
                                HeightRequest="75"
                                WidthRequest="75"
                                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" 
                                BackgroundColor="Black"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                x:Name="Bind_Title"/>
                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding Author_Views}" 
                                TextColor="Gray" 
                                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding Uploaded}" 
                                TextColor="Gray" 
                                Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Are you just looking for [Aspect](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Aspect/) property?

Comment: Close enough haha. The Fill option kinda works. It distorts the image though. Ill just require a thumbnail with the proper dimensions when a user uploads the image to prevent image warping.

Comment: It shouldn't if you use `AspectFit`, then you could embed it in it's own panel like `Grid` with the black background and height/width attributes set to it (the grid parent) so that the image would center within its parent and look a bit more uniformed. Too bad `ViewBox` isn't available.

Comment: AspectFit does not change the image any from the one i posted above. Still, the image is not centered in the blackspace.. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ya like I said, if you give the image a parent that provides the black  background and width/height requirements and center the image in it instead of trying to do it all via just the image control than it should give you a more desired result.

Comment: please provide code, i cannot get it working

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with the help of Chris W. The key was to contain the image inside a grid container. Aspect is not the right property. See below:

```
                              <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"  BackgroundColor="Black">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="72"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="128"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Image 
                                        Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" 
                                        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
```

The desired result was achieved:

[image]